# How to Download entire Folder located on S3 Bucket?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have used Java SDK and try to download Folder using **GetObjectRequest** class, but it is possible to download my folder incuding its subFolder and all files to download ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `downloadDirectory` method from `TransferManager` class:

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
File dir = new File("destDir");

MultipleFileDownload download =  transferManager.downloadDirectory("myBucket", "myKey", dir);
download.waitForCompletion();
```

As it is written in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#downloadDirectory-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-), this method:

> Downloads all objects in the virtual directory designated by the keyPrefix given to the destination directory given. All virtual subdirectories will be downloaded recursively.

Comment: how can I download a specific `subfolder`
Ex. If I give prefix as `testing/Sync` it does download all content of `Sync` but it also creates a `testing` folder in the destination location

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code to download a whole bucket (somewhat tested):

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import aws.example.s3.XferMgrProgress;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.MultipleFileDownload;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import java.io.*;
import com.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
public class S3DownloadApp {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        AWSCredentials credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider("keys.props").getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " , e);
        }

        TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withRegion("us-west-2").build()).build();//TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();

        try {
            MultipleFileDownload xfer = xfer_mgr.downloadDirectory(
                    "bucketName", null, new File("/Users/admin/Desktop/downloadFolder"));
            XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
            XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the ListBucket API to get the list of files, then download each one individually with GetObject

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use TransferManager.downloadFolder :)